# C# excel getting Document level from c# created worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, controls, office-interop, comobject

I have been trying to add a combobox or really any form controls to an excel sheet that was created on the fly. I was able to add a combobox to an excel sheet when creating an Excel Workbook project in c# and was able to access Controls.AddComboBox function in the document level (Sheet1) as so:
Fig 1

```
namespace ExcelWorkbook2{
   public partial class Sheet1{
     private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
       Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.ComboBox comboBox1  
          =this.Controls.AddComboBox(this.Range["A1", "A1"], "comboBox1");
          comboBox1.Items.Add("1 Item");
```

`this` refers to sheet1
This code works fine when creating a workbook project but when I am creating an excel sheet on the fly like so:
Fig 2

```
Application xlApp = new Application();
xlApp.Visible = true;
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
```

I am not able to go into the WorkSheet (ws) and get "controls.AddCombobox." Putting the worksheet (Fig 2) in the quickwatch says that System.___Comobject the "this" object in the other project (Fig 1) returns the value (ExcelWorkbook2.Sheet1). How can I be able to get to the Controls.AddCombobox which is casted as WorkSheetBase to use in the c# generated worksheet (Fig 2). Thanks

Comment: I haven't used too much  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel but it seems to have a nice structure similar to the conventional controls in C#. Interop (what I understand that you have in the code below) is a completely different story: it does not follow the typical .NET control structure, but the original one from VBA. The comboboxes, for example, are associated with ranges (are different than the standard .NET comboboxes). Perhaps you should get a full working code (quite a few in MSDN) to understand this new format (for you) better before coming into more specific problems.

Comment: I was able to get a working code going and added a combobox. I created a workbook project in visual studio and was able to add a control to a cell (Fig 1). I am trying to do the same for c# code generated Excel sheet (Fig 2), but the worksheet in it dosent seem to have a few of the properties possibly due to, that I am not in the excel worksheet object when creating the excel sheet

Comment: This is what I have tried to explain you in my first comment: now (in your second code) you are dealing with Office Interop, where the rules are different. My recommendation was you getting a full working code to get used to the new format (it does not even to account for comboboxes), oherwise you would be facing constant problems (because of not understanding what is going on). Here you have a link to a full working code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084/en-us. Run it, understand how Interop works and worry about comboboxes once all these ideas are completely clear to you.

Comment: PS: once your ideas are clear, bear in mind that combobox in this format is called DropDown (xlDropDown).

Comment: I actually ran and built this code before, and I also used dropdown, the dropdown dosent have events to it like the controls do, they have the ddl.onaction = (change event) that goes to a macro, I chose or would like to work with a combobox sicne I can get back to c#

Comment: Honestly, I haven't ever had this kind of problems. If I want something to be run on Excel, I rely on macros; if I want something to be run on C# and, eventually, to communicate with Excel (usually, just for information retrieval), I use C#. Thus, I am not sure about the exact point of automating Excel with C# to get the events in Excel. What is clear is that dropdown is different than a normal .NET combobox. If you are so interested in this matter, do a deeper research/testing. If you want to get help here, you should change the title/contents of your question. I cannot be of further help.

Comment: so your saying I cant use a combobox in the c# generated or Interop sort of code, since what i was trying to do was when a cell is double clicked in an excelsheet convert that cell to a combo or drop down fill it with data and validate it and convert it back to text. The combobox was ideal bec it had events to it.

Comment: (This is starting to become familiar to me) Please, understand the two ideas I am intending to explain and try to not extend this conversation too much. Your C# form is one thing and Excel (accessed via interop) is a different thing. You cannot bring the elements from your form to Excel, you have to use the ones there (e.g., dropdown). You can use comboboxes just inside forms. This is all what I am saying: Excel rules are different, learn them, accept them and, if you don't like them, just don't rely on interop.

Comment: ok, but Im not using a form for this I was using Excel Workbook project to use a combobox, if I cant use that in Excel.Interop way then thats fine

Answer (score 0):

[Controls.AddCombobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259140.aspx) is only available to the [Host Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tc6dt58x.aspx) of the  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel Namespace.  In your case, Sheet1 is a host item that is created at design-time.

Worksheets created at run-time..

> ...cannot contain any host controls or
>   Windows Forms controls.

To create a **ComboBox** on a worksheet at run-time that handles events in C# and avoid VBA:

**Assembly References:** 
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop  (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll)
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.dll)
Microsoft.VisualBasic  (Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)

**Tested / Working Code:**

```
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

// insert object shape
Excel.Shape cbo = ws.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.ComboBox.1", Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 20, 1, 100, 20);
cbo.Name = cboName;

// bind it and wire it up
MSForms.ComboBox comboBox = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.ComboBox)Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(ws, null, cboName, new object[0], null, null, null);
comboBox.FontSize = 10;
comboBox.FontBold = true;
comboBox.Change += new MSForms.MdcComboEvents_ChangeEventHandler(comboBox_Changed);

// samle data
comboBox.AddItem("Stackoverflow");
comboBox.AddItem("Cool devs");

...

private void comboBox_Changed()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Selectiong Changed!");
}
```

---

[To create a **Button** on a worksheet at run-time that handles events in C# and avoid VBA](http://To%20create%20a%20**ComboBox**%20on%20a%20worksheet%20at%20run-time%20that%20handles%20events%20in%20C#%20and%20avoid%20VBA:)

Please support with your votes and comments. Thanks, Leo.